# Some questions about the essence of IDE's debug mode

Tags: multithreading, debugging, visual-studio-code

Take the Vscode IDE as an example.
Outwardly, the debug mode seems to run in the following way:

- It just executes the statement one by one, meanwhile you can pause at any statement you want.

However, let's take multi-thread in account, then I have some questions about this mode:

- Question-1:
  When the execution is pausing at a line, no doubt that the thread where the line runs must be pausing now, but are all of other threads pausing at that time?
- Question-2:
  More importantly, Why is that?

Comment: I don't know VS Code, but if I were designing a debugger, I'd make it a configurable option. There is no reason why either choice would be more correct than the other. Threads are supposed to allow different activities within the program to happen _concurrently_ with one another, and by the strictest definition of that word, it means that there is no definite relationship between when things happen in one thread and when the same things seem to happen in any other thread. So, user's choice: Either (a) all threads are suspended, or (b) other threads run until they can no longer make progress.

Comment: P.S.: I'd have to make it clear to users that if they choose option (a), then there's no guarantee about how quickly other threads will be suspended after one thread hits a breakpoint. The most I would be able to say is that the debugger will make a sincere effort to promptly suspend them.

Comment: I have tried the IDE of Keil and found that all the threads suspend when the program is pausing at any breakpoint. The program is for an embedded product that runs FreeRTOS on a STM32 chip.